# How can I create a non-self-intersecting mesh from a line mesh?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mathematics

I am currently working on creating a 3D model of a [Lorenz system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system). I want a result fairly similar to the following picture from the Internet, minus the stand:

[image: 3D model of a lorentz attractor]

To accomplish this, I created a C++ program that outputs an OBJ where the lines of the Lorenz system are represented as lines in the OBJ file (via the l command). Then, I was going to apply the skin modifier to this OBJ in Blender to make it solid, as in the picture. When I do this, however, there are two issues. Firstly, the solid lines resemble extruded squares more than the cylinders that I prefer. Secondly, when the Lorentz system wraps back near to its self, there is overlap between the pseudo-extruded-squares. While this overlap is in and of itself not an issue, it creates mesh intersections which are highly problematic for any use of this mesh (ie. rendering, 3D printing):

[image: Cross section of the bad mesh intersections]
[image: Zoomed-out (kindof) view of the lorentz system and mesh overlaps]

How can I use Blender to transform the line OBJ file into a model with solid cylindrical lines and correct mesh overlap (similar to a union operator)?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93110/how-to-achieve-this-spline-and-particle-effect and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/trace-visualisation-in-3d-how-to-wrap-curves-onto-a-3d-mesh

Comment: don't use skin, use 3d curves... in object mode > right click > convert to curve... then in edit mode > set spline mode > bezier... then set handle type > automatic... then in curve data properties > geometry > increase bevel depth... and maybe you should export with lower resolution

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the overlap issue, but if you add a Subdivision Surface modifier then you should get circular instead of square extrusions.