# How to achieve this spline and particle effect?

Tags: animation, particles, bezier-curves, animation-nodes

How to achieve the following effect in Blender?

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7wOVM6HaWE)

I tried to apply curves to a deformed surface, but that was a bad idea. the distribution of the curves looks like a magic texture, but working with such didn't work either.

Is this something that can be done with Animation Nodes? Or with a particle system?

Comment: maybe it's just a texture which is revealed with a gradient,  the object is deformed, and at the end he has created particles?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93110/how-to-achieve-this-spline-and-particle-effect